# Base64 Encode format error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have exported data from a MSSql database and imported those data to a MySQL database using some tools.

But I have got the data incomplete.

e.g.: img is converted to binary, the binary data is not fetched completely I have binary data some thing like this.

How to convert this to readable format? Please answer this.

Comment: what do you mean by "not fetched completely" (thankfully your binary string wasn't included in your question - we don't need the wall of text it would create as the string itself isnt relevant)

Comment: Add some codes ,what you have tried so far